# SYSENTER on Intel CPUs

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, x86-64, system-calls

So AFAIK the **syscall** instruction, is AMD's equivalent to **sysenter**. So in theory one should only find a **syscall** instruction on AMD chips right? Well, apparently that's not the case, as I was messing with ntdll.dll and ntdll.dll (WOW64 version), I found that the regular version uses **syscall** whereas the ntdll.dll from WOW64 uses **sysenter**. Why is that?

Comment: I think  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16454/struggling-between-syscall-or-sysenter-windows explains the situation better.  They both exist on both manufacturer's chips.  The difference is which CPU modes they work in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All x86-64 CPUs support `syscall` in 64-bit mode; it's the only way to make 64-bit system calls.

32-bit code uses whatever the CPU supports that's faster than `int`.

---

Your info about only AMD supporting `syscall` is true *only in 32-bit user-space mode* (legacy and compat modes).

Intel's `sysenter` became the primary choice for 32-bit user-space; Intel won that fight for dominance.  Also, apparently AMD's legacy-mode `syscall` is a nightmare for the kernel to deal with; 32-bit Linux kernels don't even enable it.  64-bit Linux kernels do allow syscall from 32-bit user-space (compat mode) on AMD CPUs that support that.  (Some links to the relevant comments on kernel asm entry points in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code/46087731#46087731).)

Note that AMD CPUs don't support `sysenter` in compat mode, only legacy mode, so under a 64-bit kernel apparently you have to use `syscall` in 32-bit user-space if you want to avoid the slow `int 0x80` on AMD.

---

AMD designed AMD64 (which became x86-64), and defined a new (fairly good) behaviour for how `syscall` works *in 64-bit mode* which is different from how it works in 32-bit mode.  (e.g. in 64-bit userspace it saves the old RFLAGS into `R11`, which doesn't exist in legacy mode and thus can't be what it does there.)

**Intel adopted the 64-bit `syscall` as part of implementing their version of x86-64 in a way that's compatible with AMD's.**  (Modulo some implementation bugs, e.g. what happens if you attempt to `sysret` with a non-canonical RCX user-space return address; on Intel the fault is taken with privilege level = ring 0, but with RSP still the already-restored user-space stack => another thread can take over the kernel.  So kernels can only use it safely if RCX is known safe.)

i.e. AMD's system call instruction won for x86-64 because they designed AMD64 while Intel was betting on IA-64 (Itanium); their syscall instruction became the only standard that anyone uses on x86-64 because there's no reason to use anything else.  `syscall` is efficient and meets the needs of kernel devs.

Dispatching to pick an instruction that works on the current CPU is thus unnecessary.

---

**https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16454/struggling-between-syscall-or-sysenter-windows explains more details.**