# Calling system API from 32-bit processes under Linux 64-bit

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64, cpu-architecture, system-calls, osdev

Linux 64 bit on x86_64 employs 4 segment descriptors for code and data segments for userspace and kernelspace.

AFAIK a call to system API from a 64-bit process is done executing the `syscall` instruction from ring 3 (usermode) code segment. Then `sysret` executed in kernel mode returns control to the calling 64-bit process switching back the `CS` segment selector to point to the 64-bit usermode code segment.

What about 32-bit processes ? From Intel SDM `syscall` is not supported in `IA-32e` compatibility mode.

P.s. I'm aware of on Windows 64 bit, 32-bit applications are supported via Wow64 subsystem and a call into system API is done switching the logical CPU/core from 32-bit compatibility mode to 64-bit mode in userspace. The call to system API is done actually from 64-bit mode and upon returning from it the logical CPU is then switched back again in compatibility mode.

Comment: Usually we use libc, and it takes care to perform the system calls (with one of the many different methods available, on 32-bit they will use older methods)

Comment: 32-bit applications usually use `int $0x80` which is 128 interrupt vector (check https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S#L935).

Comment: @k1r1t0 so Linux 64-bit kernel executes `iret` to return from 128 software interrupt vector's handler into 32-bit compatibility mode. It reloads segment registers with the usermode selectors in compatibility mode and in turns the logical CPU fetches the corresponding descriptors from in-memory GDT.

Comment: `sysenter` for 32-bit user-space, or legacy `int 0x80`.  AMD CPUs support `syscall` from 32-bit user-space, but Intel doesn't.  (Intel only added the 64-bit version of `syscall` when adopting AMD's AMD64.)  See https://blog.packagecloud.io/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/

Comment: @PeterCordes so to be independent from Intel 64 or AMD64, Linux 64-bit systems employ `int 0x80` for 32-bit processes's system calls running in compatibility mode.

Comment: No, the VDSO uses `sysenter` if available.  See the linked article.  Also, possible duplicates: [Syscall or sysenter on 32 bits Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15598700) and/or [OsDev syscall/sysret and sysenter/sysexit instructions enabling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46022184) and [SYSENTER on Intel CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60608484) (AMD CPUs don't support `sysenter` in compat mode, only legacy, so Linux on modern AMD uses 32-bit `syscall`.  Note that AMD gives is compat-mode semantics similar to 64-bit mode, a bit different from legacy mode.)

Comment: See https://www.amd.com/content/dam/amd/en/documents/processor-tech-docs/programmer-references/24594.pdf#page=510

Comment: @PeterCordes so it is up to VDSO choose which method employ to perform a system call (i.e on IA-32e compat mode via `sysenter` and on AMD64 compat mode via 32-bit `syscall`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://blog.packagecloud.io/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/.

The recommended way to make system calls from 32-bit code in Linux is to `call` into the VDSO, a "library" of code+data that the kernel maps into the address-space of every executable.  The kernel chooses at bootup which instructions to put into it, depending on what the CPU supports.

##### 64-bit kernel, 64-bit user-space (64-bit mode)

- Glibc uses `syscall` directly, only calling a VDSO wrapper for system calls like `clock_gettime` and `getpid` that can run purely in user-space.  All x86-64 CPUs support `syscall` from 64-bit user-space

##### 64-bit kernel, 32-bit user-space (compat mode sub-mode of long mode)

- On Intel CPUs, x86-64 Linux's 32-bit VDSO system-call wrapper uses `sysenter`.
  AMD only supports `sysenter` in legacy mode, if at all.
- On AMD CPUs, x86-64 Linux's 32-bit VDSO system-call wrapper uses `syscall`.  The 64-bit kernel side has similar semantics between 64-bit and compat mode user-space.  Intel CPUs only support `syscall` in full 64-bit mode.
- I think all x86-64 CPUs support one or the other, so the fallback to slow `int 0x80` is never needed.  I don't know which one is supported by CPUs from Via or Zhaoxin or other vendors.

##### 32-bit kernels (legacy mode)

- (Intel and AMD): The VDSO uses `sysenter` if available.  Intel CPUs were the first to support this.  AMD added support for `sysenter` (in legacy mode only, not compat mode) to their CPUs some time after adding legacy-mode `syscall`.
- Otherwise it uses `int 0x80`.  Only ancient CPUs from either vendor are stuck with this.

AMD CPUs support `syscall` in legacy mode with different semantics from long mode, but Linux doesn't use that even if available.  According to [kernel comments in `entry_64_compat.S` which defines the entry points from compat mode into a 64-bit kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S#L155), *Linux disables the SYSCALL instruction on 32-bit kernels because the SYSCALL instruction in legacy/native 32-bit mode (as opposed to compat mode) is sufficiently poorly designed as to be essentially unusable.*  This is part of a long comment on the compat-mode entry-point for `syscall` for AMD CPUs, which *is* used.

Intel CPUs support `sysenter` from 64-bit user-space, but Linux never uses that, only `syscall`. (Intel manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sysenter)

The history here is that before AMD64 existed, both vendors added their own fast-system-call instructions as extensions.  AMD's was apparently not well designed, which is why it has different kernel-side semantics in 64-bit mode.

For x86-64, each vendor kept more support for their own fast-system-call instruction across modes, although AMD later added support for `sysenter` in legacy mode because at least some OSes (like Linux) weren't using `syscall` in 32-bit kernels because.

---

#### Related

- https://blog.packagecloud.io/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/
- [OsDev syscall/sysret and sysenter/sysexit instructions enabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022184/osdev-syscall-sysret-and-sysenter-sysexit-instructions-enabling) all the various choices, including fun facts like that an invalid-instruction trap was the fastest way into the kernel on 386, faster than `int`, and [Windows actually used it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041215-00/?p=37003).
- [Syscall or sysenter on 32 bits Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598700/syscall-or-sysenter-on-32-bits-linux)
- https://www.amd.com/content/dam/amd/en/documents/processor-tech-docs/programmer-references/24594.pdf#page=510 AMD documentation for `syscall`.  And scroll down a couple pages in the PDF for `sysenter`, where it still clearly states in this 2023 manual that `sysenter` is only supported in legacy mode on AMD CPUs.
- [What is better "int 0x80" or "syscall" in 32-bit code on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806584/what-is-better-int-0x80-or-syscall-in-32-bit-code-on-linux)
- [Intel x86 vs x64 system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168822/intel-x86-vs-x64-system-call) - quotes the Linux kernel source's `if(vdso32_syscall())` etc. that chooses which system-call instruction sequence to use for `__kernel_vsyscall`.
- [How to invoke a system call via syscall or sysenter in inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-syscall-or-sysenter-in-inline-assembly)
- [Fastest Linux system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913091/fastest-linux-system-call/48914200#48914200) shows some of the kernel side of `sysenter` under a 64-bit kernel.
- [Why int80h instead of sysenter is used  to invoke system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136028/why-int80h-instead-of-sysenter-is-used-to-invoke-system-calls) - an old VMware on an old Intel CPU apparently didn't expose `sysenter` support.  But that was legacy mode.
- https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16454/struggling-between-syscall-or-sysenter-windows has an answer describing what's supported by Intel vs. AMD in what mode, but doesn't say what Linux actually does.

I didn't think any of those explained clearly enough about compat mode vs. legacy mode differences, so not duplicates.

Comment: How is implemented (at compile/build time) the linking of an ELF executable against `VDSO` shared library ? In the ELF executable's dynamic section there is not reference to `VDSO` shared library - i.e. no `(NEEDED)` entry for `VDSO`

Comment: From what you said, `VDSO` is actually a system-call wrapper for **all** system calls exposed by the Linux kernel (some of them are implemented in userland only whereas others in IA-32e mode are implemented via either `syscall` or `sysenter` instructions)

Comment: @CarloC: I think https://blog.packagecloud.io/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/ answers some of the details of how ELF executables find the VDSO, and what's in it.  There should be other Q&As about it on Stack Overflow as well.  The VDSO doesn't have *separate* wrapper functions for each different system call, just a few implemented in user-space, and a wrapper around the `syscall` / `sysenter` / `int 0x80` instruction itself, which I think is called with a call number in EAX and other args in EBX, ECX, etc, as a drop-in replacement for `int 0x80`.

Comment: From the link above, I believe the `VDSO` wrapper for those system calls not directly implemented in user-space, should be `_kernel_vsycall` (its underlying implementation depends on the mode the user-space process is running - i.e. 64-bit mode vs compat mode vs legacy mode). Access to such a wrapper occurs through a `call` into `_kernel_vsycall`

Comment: @CarloC: That's correct.  64-bit glibc doesn't use `_kernel_vsycall`, it just uses `syscall` directly, but it's there for software that wants to use it.  (In case some future ISA changes mean there's something other than `syscall`, but the ABI is still compatible?  IDK).

Comment: @PeterCodes However 32-bit glibc (i.e. glibc version loaded into 32 bit processes running either in legacy mode or IA-32e compat mode) should call into `VDSO` system-call wrapper, not into `_kernel_vsycall` (indeed the Linux AUX vector reports just `AT_SYSINFO_EHDR`)